# Euclid's proof on the infinity of primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Could someone shed some light on this? I perfectly understand Euclid's proof on the infinity of primes.

Let's suppose there is a largest prime, p, and then let's make a number, n, so that n = (2 x 3 x 5 x ... x p) + 1. ( The parentheses are not mandatory but they help me to visualize it better.) The new number n is a number larger than the largest prime and therefore it has to be a composite number. But if you divide n with any of the primes from 2 to p (that's all the primes), you always get a remainder of 1, so n can't be a composite number. So either there is a prime bigger than p that divides n, or n itself is a new prime number.

But I just don't understand the way my math book proves it. It begins exactly the same:

...The new number n is a number larger than the largest prime and therefore it has to be a composite number. Therefore it can be divided to it's prime factors. But because n is a sum with one of the addends being  indivisible by any prime (the number 1), the number n must also be indivisible by any prime. Therefore n is a composite number that is divisible with some larger prime than p.

The part I don't really get is "But because n is a sum with one of the addends being indivisible by any prime, the number n must also be indivisible by any prime."

Comment: "But because n is a sum with one of the addends being indivisible by any prime, the number n must also be indivisible by any prime." means $n=1+p_1 p_2 ... p_n$ then n is not divisible by any of the $p_i$ (since the remainder is 1 always.) Since it is composite, it has to be divisible by some prime other than $p_i$. Hence that prime must be greater than any of the $p_i$.

Comment: Note that by construction $n = 2\cdot 3 \cdots p + 1$, where $2,3,\dots, p$ are ALL primes no greater than $p$. :)

Answer (score 1):

In essence, Euclid shows that for every prime number there is a greater one.

An integer of the form $p_{1}\cdots p_{k} + 1$ where $p_{1} \cdots p_{k}$ are primes is not divisible by any $p_{i}$, for if some $p_{i}$ divides it then $p_{i}$ divides 1, impossible.

Comment: But how does "Because n is a sum with one of the addends being indivisible by any prime, the number n must also be indivisible by any prime." differ from, for example "Because 14 + 1 is a sum with one of the addends being indivisible by three, the number 14 + 1 must also be indivisible by three." which is just wrong?

Comment: Note that by construction $n = 2\cdot 3 \cdots p + 1$, where $2,3, \cdots, p$ are ALL the primes no greater than $p$. :) The example $14+1$ is a pseudo one, because $3$ is not a prime factor of $14$.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the the statement is confusing, and wrong, to my way of reading it;  for a simple counter-example, `3+1 =4`, which is, "a sum with one of the addends being indivisible by any prime (the number 1)", and yet the number 4 is clearly divisible by a prime (2).

I think your book may have tried for a clever way to describe it, and come out incorrect.  Your description of the proof is as I understand it.  I like the paren, which makes it more intuitive to me.

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering! You can check my answer to Gudson Chou's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put too much worth into the text. To quote it again:

> But because $n$ is a sum with one of the addends being indivisible by any prime (the number 1), the number $n$ must also be indivisible by any prime.

It simply does not follow from $n=a+b$ and $p\nmid b$ that $p\nmid a$. In this point the author forgot to mention that $p\mid a$ is an essential part of the construction. I'd say, ignore the text book and be aware that you know the proof better. Also, that proof uses (without need) that composites can be *completely* factored into a product of primes. It would be sufficient to characterize composites as properly divisible by at least one prime.